# How can I determine all the matrix A 3x3 in R such as AB=BA for all B 3x3 in R (without determinants)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, definition

Determine all the matrix A 3x3 in R such as AB=BA for all B 3x3 in R (without determinants)

Comment: Are you asking for $\{ A | AB=BA \text{ for all } B \}$?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes, your correction is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_k$ be the vector of zeroes with one in the $k$th position.

Then $Ae_ie_j^T = e_i e_j^T A$ and so $e_a^T Ae_ie_j^T e_b = e_a^T e_i e_j^T A e_b$,
or more simply
$[A]_{ai} \delta_{jb} = [A]_{jb} \delta_{ai}$.

Setting $a=i, j=b$ gives $[A]_{ii} = [A]_{jj}$ and setting $a=i$ and $j \neq b$ gives
$0=[A]_{jb}$.

Hence $A$ must be in the span of the identity.

Comment: You found the identity matrix but if we consider the identity matrix and the zero matrix, can we find other Matrix B such as AB=BA?

Comment: I didn't find the identity matrix, I found a matrix whose diagonal elements are all the same. Any matrix of the form $tI$ will do.